# How can i upload folder from my local machine to EC2 inastance

Tags: root, amazon-ec2

i have a problem in uploading the folder from my laptop to my instance on amazon. i tried a lot of commands in my local machine like

```
sudo scp  -i my_key.pem -r my_folder/path public_DNS:home/ec2-user/new_folder/
```

but got every time i tried this line

```
Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".
```

Answer (score 0):

The options for `scp` are similar to `ssh` in that you need to specify the username if you do not want to connect using your own. By having `sudo` in front of the command, you’re running `scp` as root, which is being passed to the connection string because you’ve not defined something different.

Try this:

```
scp  -i ~/.ssh/my_key.pem -r /path/to/source ec2-user@123.123.123.123:/home/ec2-user/destination/
```

Be sure to change the various details for your situation, and be sure that the destination directory already exists as it will not be created by `scp`.